# Why does java treat class scope and method scope differently when using uninitialized variables?

Tags: java, initialization, scope

Java doesn't allow you to use an variable that may not have been initialized within a method scope. An uninitialized variable within a class scope may still be returned by a class method, and the value defaults to null.

Why the different treatment of the two different scopes?

```
public class TestClass {

    Integer i;
    Double d;

    public TestClass() {
        d = 1d;
    }

    public Double getD() {
        return d;
    }

    public Integer getI() {
        return i;
    }

//  public Integer getSomeInt() {
//      Integer i;
//      return i;
//  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass myClass = new TestClass();
        System.out.println(myClass.getI().getClass());
    }
}
```

This results in a NullPointerException, but returning `i` within getSomeInt() is a compiler error because "the variable may not have been initialized".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason behind this are the limits of Java's static code analysis. The compiler is able to prove beyond doubt that you will not read a stack-allocated local var before initializing it. This is impossible to do for heap-allocated memory and therefore Java mandates that all heap-allocated storage be zeroed out before exposing a pointer to it.

The consequence of this rule is that everything heap-allocated has a default value of zero (false, null, whatever the binary zero amounts to for the type).

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. Why is it impossible for heap-allocated resources to check if they'd been initialized?

Comment: Because they can easily be published to alien code and even to other threads. This makes it theoretically impossible to ensure initialization before the first read.

Answer (score 2):

Because member variables have default value (if not initialized) and so the `I` has `null` and if you invoke method on null it will result on `NullPointerException`

and for local variables, they must be initialized before used otherwise it will turn into compile time error

> Local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. If you cannot initialize your local variable where it is declared, make sure to assign it a value before you attempt to use it. Accessing an uninitialized local variable will result in a compile-time error. [[....]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: If it is a primitive data type well and good, but if it is an object oh it throws NullPointerException when accessed and its not looking good, atleast the constraint could have been there for non primitive class members

Comment: Use constructor to initialize with default value

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple really. Member variables get automatically initialized to their default values, while local variables does not.

When you do

```
public Integer getSomeInt() {
    Integer i;
    return i;
}
```

you *hide* `this.i` and in `return i` you refer to an (uninitialized) *local* variable.

---

So **why** are member variables initialized automatically while local variables are not?

Ultimately this is a question that only the designers of the language can answer, but if I had to guess I'd say it is due to the performance issue of having to zero out all memory being allocated. When it comes to objects, it would however be a pain to force the programmer to initialize all fields explicitly.

---

From the JLS (4.12.3 Kinds of Variables):

> A class variable is created when its class or interface is prepared (§12.3.2) and
>   is initialized to a default value (§4.12.5).
>
> [...]
>
> A local variable declaration statement may contain an expression which
>   initializes the variable. The local variable with an initializing expression is
>   not initialized, however, until the local variable declaration statement that
>   declares it is executed. (The rules of definite assignment (Chapter 16, Definite
>   Assignment) prevent the value of a local variable from being used before it has
>   been initialized or otherwise assigned a value.)

Comment: +1 but I think OP is questioning a little more. He points to the different behaviour of method and class variables. So explaining why method variables are not initialized by default but class members will help I think.

Answer (score 0):

All fields are implicitly initialized in the constructor after the call to `super` but before anything else. Object references are set to `null`, primitive values are set to `0`, `false` etc.
This implicit initialization isn't done in methods.

Comment: Also, the compiler can tell by examining code flow if a local variable has been initialized.  For a member variable, it's quite a bit harder and means perusing all the different method calls.  However, there's no guarantee that any of those methods have been called.  The compiler pretty much ignores this, though tools like eclipse do a good job of telling you when a variable has never been read or written within the class it's declared in.